# How to make a dynamic html form using css and js

Tags: javascript, html, css

why is my form not adding fields when clicked. Am I missing something?
 I want to add fileds when clicked on the add anotherf ield button but it is not working.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">


$(function() {
        var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
        var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

        $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
$('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
                i++;
                return false;
        });

        $('#remScnt').live('click', function() {
                if( i > 2 ) {
                        $(this).parents('p').remove();
                        i--;
                }
                return false;
        });
});


</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
<style media="screen">
* { font-family:Arial; }
h2 { padding:0 0 5px 5px; }
h2 a { color: #224f99; }
a { color:#999; text-decoration: none; }
a:hover { color:#802727; }
p { padding:0 0 5px 0; }

input {
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid #999;
    border-radius:4px;
   -moz-border-radius:4px;
   -web-kit-border-radius:4px;
   -khtml-border-radius:4px;
  }
</style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

    <div id="p_scents">
        <p>
            <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
<style media="screen">
* { font-family:Arial; }
h2 { padding:0 0 5px 5px; }
h2 a { color: #224f99; }
a { color:#999; text-decoration: none; }
a:hover { color:#802727; }
p { padding:0 0 5px 0; }

input {
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid #999;
    border-radius:4px;
   -moz-border-radius:4px;
   -web-kit-border-radius:4px;
   -khtml-border-radius:4px;
  }
</style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

<div id="p_scents">
    <p>
        <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label>
    </p>
</div>

<script src ="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
        var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
        var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

        $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
$('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" class="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
                i++;
                return false;
        });

        $(document).live('click', '.remScnt',function() {

                        $(this).parents('p').remove();

                return false;
        });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I copied this from http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/tzpg4/4/

Comment: Probably, you use newer version of jQuery, which doesn't support live() method - use on() instead.

Comment: no still it didn't not work :(

Comment: Hm, it is working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/mn91pnux/  Adding of fields, without changes... Removal will work, after little update in generated HTML (id, which must be unique, replaced with class, event delegation added, for dynamically created elements). P.S. ID of created input fields should be unique, too - or use class there, too...

Comment: i have added all code in a single snap to clear what I actually did and by the way even on method is not working with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you included jQuery? (I don't see it in your snippet) When I click on 'Add Another Input Box' in the fiddle you provided I get another input box. include `<script src ="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>` in the head. include version 1.4.3 because it uses `live` not `on`

Comment: i have now added a complete view of the code. Edited above.  You can see for all what I did

Comment: when you click on the text in the first snippet you get another input. is't that what you want?

Comment: wait..  my browser did not picked the new editing and was refreshing on the previous one. Using ctrl+f5 helped me with it. Adding version 1.4.3 was the correct option I guess.

Answer (score 0):

no jquery and your script included in your html script. jquery file used as external javascript file, so you can add the jquery file first.
note: you must include jquery before your script that used jquery.
learn about external javascript [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp)